# I am unable to automatically append a the decimal separator again after I hit back space and remove the input until the 5th digit

Tags: javascript

I have created an input field which takes text as input I am restricting the data to only floating point    numbers. I have written a custom input listener but I am unable to automatically append the decimal separator after editing the input
i.e I add a number example 12345,67
Now after I hit backspace three times the number is 12345
Now again if I want to input data it does not allow me to do so
Now I expect the function to append a decimal separator and allow up to 2 decimal digits again.

```js
    const input = document.querySelector("#text-box");
    const decimalSeparator = ","; // custom decimal separator
    
    let lastValidValue = ""; // to store the last valid input value
    
    input.addEventListener("input", () => {
      const regex = new RegExp(`^\\d{0,5}(\\${decimalSeparator}\\d{0,2})?$`); // regex to allow up to 5 digits and at most 2 decimal places
      const value = input.value;
    
      if (value.length > 8) {
        input.value = lastValidValue; // restore last valid value
      } else if (!regex.test(value)) {
        input.value = lastValidValue; // restore last valid value
      } else {
        lastValidValue = value; // update last valid value
      }
    
      if (value.length === 5 && value.indexOf(decimalSeparator) === -1) {
        input.value = value + decimalSeparator; // append decimal after entering 5 digits
        lastValidValue = input.value; // update last valid value
      }
    
      if (
        value.indexOf(decimalSeparator) !== -1 &&
        value.split(decimalSeparator)[1].length > 2
      ) {
        input.value = value.slice(0, value.indexOf(decimalSeparator) + 3); // limit to two decimal places
        lastValidValue = input.value; // update last valid value
      }
    });
    
    input.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Backspace") {
        const value = input.value;
        const cursorPosition = input.selectionStart;
        if (value.charAt(cursorPosition - 1) === decimalSeparator) {
          input.value =
            value.slice(0, cursorPosition - 1) + value.slice(cursorPosition); // remove decimal separator
          lastValidValue = input.value; // update last valid value
          event.preventDefault();
        } else if (
          value.indexOf(decimalSeparator) !== -1 &&
          value.split(decimalSeparator)[1].length === 0
        ) {
          input.value =
            value.slice(0, cursorPosition - 1) + value.slice(cursorPosition); // remove last digit
          lastValidValue = input.value; // update last valid value
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="text-box" name="text_box" class="input-box" placeholder=""/>
```

Comment: Instead of putting your code in a fiddle, put it here on stack overflow, using the `<>` icon in the input box.

Comment: The input is blocked by the code `} else if (!regex.test(value)) {`. "123456" does not matched the regex, so if you delete the decimal separator and try to input another number, it won't allow it. You can design multiple regex for different condisions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [native HTML numeric input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" max="99999.99" min="0.00">
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="javascript:;">
  <input type="number" step="0.01" max="99999.99" min="0.00">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This won’t behave quite the same way, so take note of the differences, but unless you have a very good justification for making your application take input differently, the default behaviour is probably better.

Comment: True tried this but I have to have behavior like the code I mentioned thank you for your solution

Comment: @JoshuaJuan: Why do you have to? (The reason I didn’t suggest a fix, by the way, is that there are more problems with the approach than just the one that prompted the question, and it’s very hard to get them all right.)